# Divs always at the same spot of the background image?

Tags: css, html, background-image

currently im doing an an animation with skrollr, but one of my problems is that every object needs to be at the right place, on every screen size. The background images are all different in size (one is like 1600x1100, another 1500x1500). What do i need to do that the divs are always at the same spot on the background image on every screen size?

PS: Sorry for my bad english, im german.

Comment: You can try using `position:relative`. It will place the tags as per screen size.

Answer (score 0):

you can try making height and width in percentage.

for example :

```
height:50%;
width:60%;
```